# arquillian create database schema before test

Tags: jakarta-ee, testing, integration-testing, glassfish-3, jboss-arquillian

Hello i try to create my database schem before tests but its fail :/
this is my script:

```
CREATE TABLE OFCONVERSATION
(
  CONVERSATIONID integer NOT NULL,
  ROOM character varying(1024),
  ISEXTERNAL smallint NOT NULL,
  STARTDATE bigint NOT NULL,
  LASTACTIVITY bigint NOT NULL,
  MESSAGECOUNT integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT OFCONVERSATION_PK PRIMARY KEY (CONVERSATIONID)
);
```

and its working when i try to run that script using squirell and embedded derby.

1. first i try using annotation @CreateSchema("scripts/import.sql")
       before class test:
2. next try to using @ApplyScriptBefore
3. second i try using script:

> property name="scriptsToExecuteBeforeTest" scripts/import.sql property

but its all fails ...

```
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 9.816 sec <<< FAILURE!
getPairChat(com.test.ejb.im.service.impl.PairChatTest)  Time elapsed: 0.451 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.jboss.arquillian.persistence.dbunit.exception.DBUnitDataSetHandlingException: Unable to execute statement: CREATE TABLE OFCONVERSATION
(
CONVERSATIONID integer NOT NULL,
ROOM character varying(1024),
ISEXTERNAL smallint NOT NULL,
STARTDATE bigint NOT NULL,
LASTACTIVITY bigint NOT NULL,
MESSAGECOUNT integer NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT OFCONVERSATION_PK PRIMARY KEY (CONVERSATIONID)
);
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.ParserImpl.parseStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepMinion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.conn.GenericLanguageConnectionContext.prepareInternalStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.execute(Unknown Source
```

this is my arquillian pom import:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId>
      <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
      <version>${glassfish-embedded-all.version}</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>  

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-glassfish-embedded-3.1</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.CR3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-persistence-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Alpha6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

and my test-persistence.xml:

```
 <persistence-unit name="test-ejb" transaction-type="JTA">
  <jta-data-source>test-ds</jta-data-source>
  <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>      
  <properties>
      <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="DERBY"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.platform.class.name" value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.DerbyPlatform"/>
       <!-- <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/> --> 
      <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="ALL"/>
      <property name="eclipselink.jpa.uppercase-column-names" value="true" />
  </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
```

and glassfish-resources.xml:

```
<resources>
    <jdbc-connection-pool name="test-pool"
        res-type="javax.sql.DataSource" datasource-classname="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDataSource"
        ping="true">
        <property name="ConnectionAttributes" value="create=true" />
        <property name="DatabaseName" value="./target/derbydb" />
        <property name="Password" value="" />
        <property name="User" value="" />
    </jdbc-connection-pool>
    <jdbc-resource jndi-name="test-ds" pool-name="test-pool" />
</resources>
```

So what is wrong with that sql scripts or with my config ?

Comment: I think this might be a question for Code Reviews: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you get (or something similar as you're using Derby):

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00911: invalid character
```

further down in your stack trace then you may have stumbled on a [broken feature in Alpha6](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ARQ-1444).

Answer (score 0):

This would help you as I have removed special characters (Carriage Return , Line feed ...)

```
CREATE TABLE OFCONVERSATION(  CONVERSATIONID integer NOT NULL,  ROOM character varying(1024),  ISEXTERNAL smallint NOT NULL,  STARTDATE bigint NOT NULL,  LASTACTIVITY bigint NOT NULL,  MESSAGECOUNT integer NOT NULL,  CONSTRAINT OFCONVERSATION_PK PRIMARY KEY (CONVERSATIONID))
```

Comment: use this script with @CreateSchema("scripts/import.sql")